# How to implement Handler level authorization in asp.net core RazorPages

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, razor-pages

Authorize attribute at PageModel is not enough because it applies to all handlers in that pagemodel.
I am looking for some custom authorization lets say "Can access only if age is 18+", so how to implement same in RazorPages (Not MVC)?
Is there any neat and clear solution for this??

Comment: I have a button or handler which user can access only if he/she is 18+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to use `Authorize` attribute on individual Razor Page handlers , you can trace the feature request in [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8737) .

As a workaround , you can inject the `IAuthorizationService` and implement the authorization manually :

```
private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;
public IndexModel(ILogger<PrivacyModel> logger,  IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _authorizationService = authorizationService;
}

public async Task OnGet()
{

    var isAuthorized = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(
                                                User, "PolicyName");
    if (!isAuthorized.Succeeded)
    {
        //not pass the authorzation 
    }

}
```

And create policy to check whether the value user's age claim is over 18 as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1) .